# mysql - trouble with using group by and order by

Tags: mysql

I know this question has been asked a lot already, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for my problem.

I have a database of books a college uses and I'm trying to write an SQL statement to display the titles of books, their course numbers, and departments. I need to order them alphabetically by the title of the book and then group them by the school division. This is what I have:

```
SELECT title, course_number, department 
    FROM books 
    GROUP BY school_division 
    ORDER BY title;
```

But it only prints out 3 records when I actually have 10 in total. I'm not sure how to get it to print out all 10 records?

If I get rid of the GROUP BY then it prints out all 10 records so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: why do you want to group them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT title, course_number, department 
    FROM books 
    ORDER BY school_division,title ;
```

Do not use `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: that worked, thank you! i'm new to mysql and i didn't realize you could use ORDER BY with two different columns